# Windows 11 plays a ringing sound every second as if i've added a USB Stick

Tags: bluetooth, driver, windows-11

My Windows 11 Machine is playing the same sound as if you'd add an USB Stick but every second. The reason for that seems to be that it shows my Motherboards Wireless Bluetooth Chip every second to be able to be dismountable. I have unfortunatelly not found anything on the internet. I'm assuming Better Joy for Cemu (which is a program i've installed for bluetooth controllers) is the reason for that. I had not had any previous issues until now. Unfortunatelly i alread removed the application and used the uninstall feature, which solved nothing. I already removed the bluetooth driver from the device manager (which solves it until i reinstall the original one from gigabyte).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seemed to be not an windows related issue. I reinstalled windows, and the same thing happened.

then i unplugged my PSU, turned it off and waited 20 seconds. Restarted. Problem solved. :/